# The initializer type 'AuthRepository?' can't be assigned to the field type 'AuthRepository' in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

The error is coming on line 6 (in the first code snippet or the main code part), on authRepository part.

The main code -

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  final AuthRepository  _authRepository;
  var v;
  AuthBloc({
    @required AuthRepository? authRepository
  }) : _authRepository = authRepository super(AuthState.unknown());
```

And here is the snippet of `AuthRepository` -

```
class AuthRepository extends BaseAuthRepository {

  final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore;
  final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  AuthRepository({
    FirebaseFirestore? firebaseFirestore,
    auth.FirebaseAuth? firebaseAuth,
  })  : _firebaseFirestore = firebaseFirestore ?? FirebaseFirestore.instance,
        _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign a nullable variable to a non-nullable variable. Use syntactic sugar (`this.var` syntax) for the constructor and use positional parameter.

```dart
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  final AuthRepository  _authRepository;
  var v;
  AuthBloc(this._authRepository) : super(AuthState.unknown());
}
```

**Other Solution**

If you still want to use the required named parameter with a private member, make the `_authRepository` a nullable variable, that would require changes wherever you've used that variable (`_authRepository`).

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  final AuthRepository?  _authRepository;
  var v;
  AuthBloc({
    @required AuthRepository? authRepository
  }) : _authRepository = authRepository super(AuthState.unknown());
}
```

Comment: Then this error is coming on authRepository on line 6 (in your code) - The parameter 'authRepository' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.

Comment: Updated my answer.